# Converting a Cloud Storage file into a BigQuery Table/Dataset to then later query

Tags: java, eclipse, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I've been at this for a couple days now but it seems the examples don't work or perhaps I have an environment issue so I'm hoping someone can help.

**Here's what I've tried and works:**

- I have Eclipse Neon on Mac.
- Installed All Google API SDKs available from the guide below as well
  as here:
  `https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.6`
- I followed this Quickstart succesfully:
  `https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse`

So I have an Eclipse Dataflow Project that is able to read and write to CloudStorage. Awesome stuff.

**GOAL/ISSUE**

I now want to take the data from GCS, convert it into a BigQuery Dataset. For each file I'd like to create a new data set. Those details aren't really important for the question, although it would be a nice cherry on top, because where I'm stuck is a simple Hello World example of BigQuery with Eclipse or even CLI Tools. Any working examples would be appreciated or a simple nudge to existing documentation that has working samples. Again maybe it's how I'm compiling with Eclipse or Maven but I don't see any way to load a Google API based project.

**ECLIPSE**

In Eclipse I tried a bunch of things to simply test out BigQuery API:

1. loading a new Java Project by loading the `google-cloud-java-master` repository found `https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java`

[Eclipse Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imd3X.png)

2. I proceeded to try to load the examples from the "google-cloud-examples" directory. This seems to have an issue because when I right click the `CreateTableAndLoadData` Class and choose to Run it, I get an error saying "Selection does not contain Main type". Which makes me feel stupid because there is a main function there.

**GOOGLE EXAMPLES from `java-doc-samples`**

I then moved on to Trying Google's own examples which are actually in a different repo called java-doc-samples`https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/SimpleApp.java`

Google doc: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api#bigquery-simple-app-query-java

I loaded these into Eclipse but I got a ton of errors during compilation.
Main errors:

Either `com.google.cloud` wasn't able to resolve or the package `com.google.cloud.examples.bigquery.snippets` wouldn't resolve. I could not get any of it to compile. The Class names were a bit different so I tried changing those with Eclipse auto-suggest but in the end BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance() ended up being an undefined method.

**CLI `gcloud`**

In the CLI I tried MVN compiling and running the `google-cloud-exmaples/...CreateTableAndLoadData.java`

```
mvn -X compile exec:java  
-Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.examples.bigquery.snippets.CreateTableAndLoadData    
-Dexec.args="--project=myuniqueproject \
--stagingLocation=gs://myuniquebucket/staging/ \
--runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner"
```

but I get these errors:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project google-cloud-examples: Could
>   not resolve dependencies for project
>   com.google.cloud:google-cloud-examples:jar:0.8.2-alpha-SNAPSHOT: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   com.google.cloud:google-cloud:jar:0.8.2-alpha-SNAPSHOT,
>   com.google.cloud:google-cloud-nio:jar:0.8.2-alpha-SNAPSHOT: Could not
>   find artifact com.google.cloud:google-cloud:jar:0.8.2-alpha-SNAPSHOT
>   -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

> I now want to take the data from GCS, convert it into a Bigquery Dataset

I'm going to assume you meant "*Table*" and not "*Dataset*". A dataset is a collection of BigQuery tables.

You could save yourself a lot of work, and simply use a federated source to read the file(s) directly from GCS into BigQuery.

More info -> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources

Comment: not looking to save myself a ton of work as much as I'm trying to accomplish my goal. My question is about using BigQuery API's to move a GCS file into a Table and how not one example out there seems to actually compile. The performance implications of what you suggest are very limited for very large data files not to mention possible data loss if BQ is reading while the GCS file is being updated.

Comment: 1) you never mentioned that the files would be changing in your original question 2) what makes you think there is a massive performance hit? It's all running on Google infrastructure, so it's still incredibly fast -> https://shinesolutions.com/2016/03/30/creating-a-serverless-etl-nirvana-using-google-bigquery/ 3) the examples I've used compile just fine.